# Using TRY / CATCH to perform INSERT / UPDATE

Tags: sql-server, exception, try-catch, upsert

I have this pattern in a number of stored procedures

```
-- Table1
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
[data] [varchar](512) NULL
[count] INT NULL

-- 'data' is unique, with a unique index on 'data' in 'Table1'
BEGIN TRY 
    INSERT INTO Table1 (data, count) SELECT @data,1;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    UPDATE Table1 SET count = count + 1 WHERE data = @data;
END CATCH
```

I've been slammed [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30710135/abstracting-out-a-query-to-a-stored-procedure-makes-it-run-very-slowly) for using this pattern

> You should never have exception "catching" in your normal logic flow. (Thus why it is called an "exception"..it should be exceptional (rare). Put a exists check around your INSERT. "if not exists (select null from Data where data = @data) begin /* insert here */ END

However, I can't see a way around it in this instance. Consider the following alternative approaches.

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (data,count) 
SELECT @data,1 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 FROM Table1 WHERE data = @data)
```

If I do this, it means every insert is unique, but I can't 'catch' an update condition.

```
DECLARE @id INT;  
SET @id = (SELECT id FROM Table1 WHERE data = @data)

IF(@id IS NULL)
    INSERT INTO Table1 (data, count) SELECT @data,1;
ELSE 
    UPDATE Table1 SET count = count + 1 WHERE data = @data;
```

If I do this, I have a race condition between the check and the insert, so I could have duplicates inserted.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
   DECLARE @id INT;  
   SET @id = (SELECT id FROM Table1 WHERE data = @data)

   IF(@id IS NULL)
       INSERT INTO Table1 (data, count) SELECT @data,1;
   ELSE 
       UPDATE Table1 SET count = count + 1 WHERE data = @data;
END TRANSACTION
```

If I wrap this in a `TRANSACTION` it adds more overhead. I know `TRY/CATCH` also brings overhead but I *think* `TRANSACTION` adds more - anyone know?.

People keep telling me that using `TRY/CATCH` in normal app logic is *BAD*, but won't tell me *why*

Note: I'm running SQL Server 2005 on at least one box, so I **can't use `MERGE`**

Comment: You just killed the first answer that came to my mind i.e. Merge. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update and if it's failed - to insert new.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    UPDATE t
    SET
            t.count = t.count + 1
    FROM Table1 t
    WHERE t.data = @data

    IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Table1
        (data, count)
        VALUES
        (@data, 1)
    END
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: As per OP: Note: I'm running SQL Server 2005 on at least one box, so I can't use `MERGE`.

Comment: @FelixPamittan terrible :( you can make a workaround like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621241/can-i-use-the-merge-statement-in-sql-server-2005

Comment: `MERGE` also has a bunch of unresolved issues, so I'm hesitant to use it. read more here: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

Comment: @roryok I edited my answer, I hope it'll help you. It seems like an answer of Dan, but I think, exists cheking is not necessary

Comment: @Backs is a transaction faster than a try/catch?

Comment: @roryok of cause, generating exception is expensive operation. try to execute both varinats 50000 times. my variant takes about 2 second, try-catch variant takes abount 9 seconds

Comment: @roryok you are wellcome!

Answer (score 0):

The explicit transaction is the cost of doing business with a conditional INSERT/UPDATE in order to address concurrency.  The example below uses locking hints to a avoid race condition with this code.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

INSERT  INTO Table1
        ( data
        , count
        )
        SELECT  @data
              , 1
        WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                             FROM   Table1 WITH ( UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK )
                             WHERE  data = @data );

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    UPDATE  Table1
    SET     count = count + 1
    WHERE   data = @data;

COMMIT;
```

If the more common path is the `UPDATE`, try that first followed by the conditional `INSERT`.

Comment: does this perform better than the `TRY / CATCH` approach?